# Service owns disposable Repository that owns disposable DbContext - Dispose IDisposables injected with Unity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, dependency-injection, idisposable

I have a service, a repository and a `DbContext`. The repository owns the `DbContext` and the service owns the repository.

Should my repository implement `IDisposable`? If so, should my service also implement `IDisposable` and dispose the repository?

I guess a more general question could be, if I have a class that has a reference to a class, that has a reference to another class, ... (and so on) ..., that has a reference to an unmanaged or managed disposable resource - should they *all* implement `IDisposable`?

Comment: Yes, this is what  `Disposable` is (theoretically) for. It allows convenient cleanup of managed resources throughout an object graph. That said, unless your repository is similarly short lived (either because the service is short lived, or it creates new ones), it shouldn't be holding on to a `DbContext`. You should create and dispose a `DbContext` typically within a single `using` block.

Comment: Generally it is good practice to dispose `DbContext`, but if you don't have a lot of repositories (and hence contexts) popping in and out of existence, and your code would be excessively convoluted by implementing disposable all the way up from your context, I would say don't worry about it. The GC will eventually clean up your context either way, and an inactive `DbContext` isn't hanging on to any important resources.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed. I have Unity dependency resolver set to inject a dbcontext through the constructor of the repository. The context should be bound to the request scope. Does this have any influence on the cleanup of the dbcontext? Also, please create an answer so I can accept it. :-)

Comment: I fully disagree. You must always dispose a DbContext, because it hold important resources. The simplest way to prove it is that you wouldn't implement IDisposable if there are no resources to free up (connection to the DB, tracked objects, etc.). So you must excplicitly dispose the objects (generally with a `using` block. The problem is that Unity doesn't provide any way to dispose the objects

Comment: From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) about lifetime managers in Unity: "When the container is disposed, it calls the Dispose method of the object and allows it to be garbage collected. Therefore, you must ensure that your code does not maintain a reference to the object." Does this not mean that Unity calls dispose on the DbContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity DI doesn't have a way to Dispose the objects when their lifetime has finished, and you cannot leave them there until the GC decides to collect them.

*Theoretically there are DI frameworks that implement the Register/Resolve/Release, and Release would be the place to call dispose, but Unity doesn't implement the Release part. I don't know if there are other frameworks which can do that in .NET.*

With Unity, there are two solutions:

### 1) The easy hack

Don't inject the DbContext, but resolve it from the container in the places where you need it, so that you can control it's disposal

```
using(var ctx = container.Resolve<MyDbContext>())
{
}
```

**ALARM! ALARM! Service Locator anti-pattern**

### 2) the smart solution

Inject a factory that can provide you the DbContext when you need it. If you do so, instead of injecting a DbContext you inject a class that can provide you the DbContext when you need it: a factory. You can register your factory as a singleton in the DI container, because you'll be using it continuosly

```
using(var ctx = DbContextFactory.GetContex())
{
}
```

Your factory could look something like this:

```
public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
   public DbContext GetDbContext()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

So that it can be injected via constructor injection:

```
public MyService(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
{
}
```

And, as explained, there is no reason to not register it as a singleton: you can safely and happyly use the same Factory to build lots of Db Contexts!

*NOTE: it's much better if you use an abstract factory that, instead of returning concrete objects returns an interface implementation, it's this little change*

```
public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
   public IDbContext GetDbContext()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

You can read this for more information and samples:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220640/factory-pattern-and-or-dependency-injection
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778264/Dependency-Injection-of-an-Abstract-Factory

Answer (score 2):

In terms of IDisposable, it's my opinion that if an object implements IDisposable you need to Dispose it even though there are examples where not calling IDisposable does not cause any issues.  But that's an implementation detail that it may not be safe to depend on (as opposed to the IDisposable contract).

You don't mention the type of service you are using but you do mention you are using Unity.

If it's a Web API Service you can use the [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/3.5.1404) (along with the [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/).  This will give a [PerRequestLifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) which will give a singleton per request (not sure if you need this or not but it's a common scenario).

In addition, an IHttpModule, UnityPerRequestHttpModule, is installed which will dispose IDisposable object instances at the end of the HTTP request (that are registered with the PerRequestLifetimeManager).

If using another service stack (e.g. WCF) then you could implement something similar yourself or use the factory approach outlined in JotaBe's answer.

Comment: +1, BUT I knew this lifetime manager, but i didn't know that it could dispose instances by adding that http module. However, if several different services which depend on the DbContext are used on a single request, they will all share the same DbContext, and it could lead to problems. The documentation of the lifetime manager itself says: "Although the PerRequestLifetimeManager lifetime manager works correctly and can help in working with stateful or thread-unsafe dependencies within the scope of an HTTP request, it is generally not a good idea to use it when it can be avoided."